# QSqlQuery not selecting a record from postgresql

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, postgresql-10

relevant code:

```
this->user = ui->user->text();
this->pass = ui->pass->text();

QSqlQuery qry;
qry.prepare("select pass from users WHERE user =:user");
qry.bindValue(":user",this->user);

if(qry.exec()){
    qDebug () << "query.exe success";
}
    qDebug() << " ERROR " << qry.lastError();

if(qry.first()){
    qDebug() <<  qry.value(0).toString();

     }
```

`qry.first()` is never executed `qry.lastError()` returns an empty error string, which I understand means there's no error. However using a `delete from users` works. `this->user` is string that matches what's in the database table `users`. But the query is never executed.

table `users'` columns are: `id`, `user (varchar)`, `pass(varchar)`
I have looked at many places for an answer but haven't found one.

Comment: have you tried `query.next()`

Comment: @Mohammad yes, qry.next() is also never executed.

Comment: what does `qDebug() << qry.lastQuery();` show ?

Comment: @MohammadKanan ""select pass from users where user = ?"" and with named binding "select pass from users where user = :user" the binding doesnt work.

Comment: I fixed this problem. I used qt5.8. made a bit of change 

`qry.prepare("select pass from users where username 
=:user");
qry.bindValue(":user",this->user);"`
This works. However qry.lastQuery() doesn't show the named bound value. It just shows the original query.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the query works without binding first.

Your driver could be not supporting **named** binding!

Try binding values using **positional** placeholders:

```
qry.prepare("select pass from users WHERE user = ?");
qry.bindValue(0,this->user);
```

Comment: you mean addBindValue(this->user); theres no matching function bindValue(QString&). Anyway after your solution the qry.lastQuery() still shows "select pass from users where user = ?"

Comment: Yes its either `bindValue(0,this->user);` or `qry.addBindValue(this->user);`

Comment: so positional binding also doesn't work, what could be causing this? Should I start a new question?

Comment: Which Qt Version ?

Comment: it is Qt 5.3.2.

Comment: Can you check tranaction log at DB side?

Comment: no, I actually don't know how to view log on pgadmin4, I will look into that. However I change user column to username and tried "select pass from users where username = 'abc' " this works. It's a little different syntax with postgresql. Binding still a no.

Comment: I am a little lost, should I simply upgrade my qt version to latest?

Comment: May be you can create BUG report